# Creating a preview of a data set from the arcpy command line

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am creating an ArcPy tool that will be run from the commandline, and I would like the user to be able to easily create a map of results. This would essentially be equivalent to the "Preview" window in ArcCatalog.

Is there any simple way of creating such a plot while using ArcPy outside of the ArcGIS Pro GUI? I have searched through ESRI's online documentation but could not find a clear answer.

Comment: Maybe check out https://community.esri.com/thread/74824

Comment: Thanks, Nick, that looks like it should work! I will give it a try.

Comment: You've tagged your Q. [arcgis-pro] but mention ArcMap in the text.  Which is it?

Comment: Hi user2856, sorry for the ambiguity. I am referring to ArcGIS-Pro but may be using Desktop terminology since that's what I know most intimately. Do the edits help?

Comment: Support also pointed me to a potential solution using pandas/folium: https://towardsdatascience.com/making-3-easy-maps-with-python-fb7dfb1036